# Gatsby gatsby-remark-relative-images does not convert yaml absolute image path to relative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify-cms

I am currently trying to resolve an absolute path in yaml file to relative so it can be query using graphql in gatsby. The absolute path are provided from netlify-cms.

When the same path are being placed in md file and uses `gatsby-remark-relative-images` to convert it to relative path, it has no problem at all, but the same does not apply to yaml.

The image file are placed in `static/img/` and the path provided by cms is `/img/xxx.jpg`

***src/data/pages/index.yaml***

```
page: index
slider:
  - image: /img/1_new.jpg
    url: ""
  - image: /img/2_new.jpg
    url: ""
  - image: /img/3_new.jpg
    url: ""
```

***gatsby-config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
        name: 'data',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/img`,
        name: 'uploads',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: 'pages',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/assets/images`,
        name: 'images',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /\.inline\.svg$/,
        },
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-yaml-plus`,
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
            options: {
              name: 'uploads',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 2048, // must specify max width container
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files',
            options: {
              destinationDir: 'static',
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          `gatsby-remark-widows`,
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms',
      options: {
        modulePath: `${__dirname}/src/cms/cms.js`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify', // make sure to keep it last in the array
  ],
  // for avoiding CORS while developing Netlify Functions locally
  // read more: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-proxy/#advanced-proxying
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      '/.netlify/functions/',
      proxy({
        target: 'http://localhost:9000',
        pathRewrite: {
          '/.netlify/functions/': ``,
        },
      })
    )
  },
}
```

Also, here is where it convert the absolute path in node into relative path

***gatsby-node.js***

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  fmImagesToRelative(node) // convert image paths for gatsby images

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

Finally, here is where it define the netlify-cms configuration

***static/admin/config.yml***

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master

media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img

collections:
  - label: "Data"
    name: "data"
    files:
    - name: "index"
      label: "Index"
      file: "src/data/pages/index.yml"
      fields:
        - {label: "Page", name: "page", widget: hidden, default: "index"}
        - label: "Slider"
          name: "slider"
          widget: list
          fields:
            - {label: "Image", name: "image", widget: image}
            - {label: "Url", name: "url", widget: string, required: false}
```

***Error Message***

```
 ERROR 

GraphQL Error Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.

  file: /home/gaara/JS/iconic-starter-netlify-cms/src/pages/index.js

   1 |
   2 |   query IndexPage {
   3 |     pagesYaml(page: { eq: "index" }) {
   4 |       id
   5 |       slider {
   6 |         desktop {
>  7 |           image {
     |                 ^
   8 |             childImageSharp {
   9 |               fluid(maxWidth: 2000, quality: 90) {
  10 |                 aspectRatio
  11 |                 presentationWidth
  12 |                 src
  13 |                 srcSet
  14 |                 sizes
  15 |               }
  16 |             }
  17 |           }


⠙ extract queries from components
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I had already made sure that all the image exists inside the `static/img/` folder. I had also made several attempt in restarting the server so to avoid image not loading issue. The image path that given from netlify-cms should stay as `/img/xxx.jpg` because there is a lot of other markdown files uses it and has no problem in resolving the path.

May I know is there any configuration problem which I did wrong or miss out that causing the `gatsby-remark-relative-images` not being able to resolve the file path?

Answer (score 1):

`gatsby-remark-relative-images` is a plugin that only works with markdown files handled by `gatsby-transformer-remark`.

The recent-ish graphql schema customization update allows new solution that's independent of file types. You can explore the official docs on the topic here: [Customize the Graphql Schema (gatsby docs)](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/)

Instead modifying the image paths before gatsby gets to it (like with gatsby-remark-relative-images), we'd customize the graphql schema so that the image field (`slider.desktop.image` in your case) resolves to the image file node instead.

Please note that the node types below are just loose examples & you should go to your graphiql endpoint (i.e. `localhost:8000/graphiql`) to find the correct type names.

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes, createFieldExtension } = actions

  createFieldExtension({
    name: 'fileByStaticPath',
    extend: () => ({
      resolve: (src, args, ctx, info) => {
        // look up original string value
        const { fieldName } = info
        const partialPath = src[fieldName]

        // TODOS
        // - join path to create the correct image file path
        // - query the file node with `context.nodeModel.runQuery`
        // - return the file node if exists
      }
    })
  })


  const typeDefs = `
    type YamlSliderDesktop @infer {
      image: File @fileByStaticPath
    }

    type YamlSlider @infer {
      desktop: YamlSliderDesktop
    }

    type PagesYaml implements Node @infer {
      slider: YamlSlider
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

---

I found myself doing this pretty often, so I wrote a plugin for it: [gatsby-schema-field-absolute-path (github)](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-schema-field-absolute-path).

I also wrote a bit more in depth about this over here on my blog ([byderek.com](https://www.byderek.com/post/a-stackoverflow-question--a-use-case-for-gatsbys-field-extension)), but really, nothing that you won't find in the Gatsby official docs, just explained in a different language.

Hope it helps!